# Zend Framework with PHP, changing class labels

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo

I am using Zend Framework with Dojo to make tab containers.  I need for the dt tags to be createEventForm-waiverDetail-addElement-label instead of addElement-label.  However I cannot figure it out.  You can see them as the id in the following code snippet

http://pastie.org/780362

I have looked and looked for this.  I think it may be something in the decorators.  The following is the decorators that I set for the Zend Dojo Form:

```
$this->setDecorators(
    array(
        'FormElements',
        array(
            'TabContainer', 
            array(
                'id' => 'tabContainer',
                'style' => 'width: 100%; height: 500px;',
                'dijitParams' => array(
                    'tabPosition' => 'top'
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'DijitForm',
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future users of the site that are looking for similar information.  In order to do this you must reset the decorator stack, setting the id while you are doing it.